# Carrocel não mostra foto

Tags: php, codeigniter, lógica

Bem, tenho um carrocel onde eu pego as "imagens"(na verdade são só só nomes das imagens) no banco de dados e faço um foreach no carrocel mais as imagens não aparecem.
Quando exibo o código fonte vejo que as imagens estão incorporadas as paginas e elas veem na pagina mais não mostra as imagens no carrocel.
O que poderia ser?

Meu carrocel:

```
<div id="content">
<div class="container no-padding">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Carousel Slideshow -->
        <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Carousel Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <!-- End Carousel Indicators -->
            <!-- Carousel Images -->

            <?php
                foreach ($imagem as $value) {
                    if ($value->imagem_status == true) {?>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/site/'.$value->imagem_link) ?>">
                        </div>

                  <?php }
                }
            ?>



            </div>
            <!-- End Carousel Images -->
            <!-- Carousel Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
            <!-- End Carousel Controls -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Carousel Slideshow -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Gostaria saber se tem uma solução para isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenho um exemplo que uso aqui e funciona normal, a unica coisa que parece está faltando é na **div da imagem** um **class="item active"** por que o carrosel precisa ter uma div com **uma class active**.

Segue o exemplo que tenho:

`

```
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <?php foreach($slider as $slide):?>
            <div <?php echo ($slide->class == 1)?"class='item active ctrl'":"class='item ctrl'"?>>
                <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/slider/'.$slide->image);?>" alt="Destaques">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3><?php echo $slide->titulo; ?></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>`
```

Comment: E essa variavel class e o que ?
$slide->class

Comment: isso é um if simplificado é a mesma coisa que fazer:

`if($slide->class == 1){
    echo "<div class='item active ctrl'>";
}else{
  echo "<div class='item ctrl'>";
}`

A variavel class vem do banco com valor 1 ou  0 para definir qual slide será o primeiro ativo.